# Сохранение изображения с помощью библиотеки GD

Tags: apache-modules, gd, php, linux

У меня Linux, а на нем Apache. Использую библиотеку GD для PHP.
Не могу сохранить изображение вызовом

```
imagePNG($image, '1.png');
```

Изображение не сохраняется. По крайней мере по имени этот файл не находится. Что делать? Может, что в настройках не так?
Может быть, проблема в самой библиотеке?
Полный код:

```
$image = imagecreate(255, 255);
imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
$c = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 0);
imagestring($image, 4, 3, 1, 'iloveinukraine.com', $c);

header('Content-Type: image/png;');

imagePNG($image, '1.png');
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: > У меня Linux, а на нем Apache.

А не слыхали что на LAMP для оптима нужно много чего докидывать, ато и xml пропарсить невыйдет однажды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно просто отдавать клиенту то можно так:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png;');
imagePNG($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

А вообще, там либо с правами на создание файлов в этой директории ограничение. Кстати, файл должен создаваться в той директории, где лежит Ваш скрипт.

И еще возможно ошибаюсь, но попробуйте выполнить скрипт без imagedestroy($image), возможно он удаляет и файл.

Comment: Ага, у меня на локальном сервере всё выполнилось отлично. Значит скорее всего там вопрос с правами на запись.

Comment: [Tue Nov 08 21:50:51 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  imagepng(): Unable to open '12345.png' for writing: Permission denied in /var/www/xxx/ex.php on line 15

я не знаю под какими правами должен этот файл работать. работал под рутом. а под каким он имеет право писать?

Comment: Не на файл доступ. А на папку, в которой создаете файл. Для безопасности эта папка должна быть доступна для записи и находится выше корневой директории вашего сайта.
Например, если у вас сайт находится в root/public_html, то папку, в которой будете создавать файлы создайте, например рядом root/images

Comment: а на какого юзера надо права давать? если images под рутом, то не сохраняет и где нужно указать что сохранять надо в папке images???

Comment: так. все вышло.

а папку вы посоветовали поставить выше чем мой проект - это делается для того, чтобы кто-то не смог выполнить просмотр доступных файлов через сервер?

Comment: На всех, поэтому и делать выше корневой папки. 
imagePNG($image, '../../images/1.png'); - примерно так, если судить по сообщению ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Какой дистрибутив Linux? Быть может нет пакета libpng или вообще нет php-gd :)

phpinfo покажите

Comment: Или что-то другое надо???
`gd

GD Support enabled

GD Version 2.0

FreeType Support enabled

FreeType Linkage with freetype

FreeType Version 2.4.2

T1Lib Support enabled

GIF Read Support enabled

GIF Create Support enabled

JPEG Support enabled

libJPEG Version 6b

PNG Support enabled

libPNG Version 1.2.44

WBMP Support enabled


Directive Local Value Master Value

gd.jpeg_ignore_warning 0 0`

Comment: Вроде все на месте, тогда смотреть error_log, он, в зависимости от дистрибутива, будет гдето в /var/log/httpd/error_log

Answer (score 0):

вы бы для теста абсолютный путь указали ... да error log покурили не ленитесь покурить.

```
imagePNG($image, '/tmp/1.png');
```

а так, работает ?

Comment: и где этот error log???

а ваш пример не работает. я даже пытался записывать в Домашнюю папку